# Pdf version information not correct using pdfbox

Tags: pdf, version, pdfbox

We are having a pdf which when opened in Acrobat Reader shows a version of 1.5 but when using Pdfbox(version 1.8.3) the version shows 1.3.

The code that we are using:

```
`aDocument.getDocument().getVersion()`
```

where aDocument is an instance of PDDocument.
Pdfbox version we are using is 1.8.3

Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What PDFBox version are you using? Always mention the version.

Answer (score 1):

[Hitesh Saliya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4247579/hitesh-saliya) already discussed that PDF in his question [*Adobe showing incorrect PDF Version (of PDF) in Properties*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905919/adobe-showing-incorrect-pdf-version-of-pdf-in-properties). In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26906034/1729265) it became appearant that

- version 1.3 was correct if one only takes the version header into account (there are no **Version** catalog entries in the document to consider);
- *at least* version 1.5 was correct if one also took into account that object streams, cross reference streams, layers, and transparency are used.

In a way, therefore, both PDFBox and Adobe Reader are correct.

Thus, one first has to decide what one considers *the version* of a PDF document to be.

- Is it the version the PDF file **claims to be**?

  As a special case, what about PDFs claiming different versions? E.g. different entries in header and catalog, or different entries in different incremental updates.
- Is it the version a chosen **indicator program** (e.g. Adobe Reader in a fixed version) **recognizes** for the PDF?
- Is it the smallest / the largest version **according to the respective PDF reference/specification the PDF is valid**?

  Could even any version in that range be a correct answer (resulting not in **the version** but **the versions** of a document)?
- Some **mixture** of the above, e.g. the maximum of the version claimed and the lowest version according to which the PDF is valid?

Seriously, though, one can hardly expect anything more than option 1 to be implemented in a general purpose PDF library.

Comment: This file annoys me - lets take the most literal answer here which is the first one you mention. The "version the PDF file claims to be". That's usually the only reasonable answer anyway because all other answers require a lot of analysis of the document. If we take that interpretation of the question, why does this file report 1.5 in Adobe Reader (or callas pdfToolbox for that matter)? If I read the PDF specification on version numbers, I think it should report 1.3... (there's no catalog key, no extensions dict, nothing but the header...). Any thoughts on this?

Comment: *why does this file report 1.5 in Adobe Reader (or callas pdfToolbox for that matter)* - I assume they show the fourth variant, *the maximum of the version claimed and the lowest version according to which the PDF is valid*, for the validity taking at least object and cross reference stream existence into account. They don't want to reflect the version number as described in the specification but a criterion for which reader version can display the file properly.

Comment: That's what I'm assuming as well, but I'm not happy with it so I'll pursue it with Adobe. As far as I know Adobe Reader is supposed to be a conforming PDF reader and as such it should display the version number in accordance with the PDF specification. And in this case I don't believe it does...